# How make relations in elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that elastic supports child/parent relationship, but child can have only one parent.

- If I'm not using this relationship and just write `parent_id`, how can I load all child like inner hits with all parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the info about the children from the same parent, use the query:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "parent_id": {
            "type": "my-child",
            "id": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

This will bring back all the documents where the join field is set to `my-child` (children) and with the parent id equals to 1.

It's interesting, I haven't queried for more than one parent. If you want to get all the children from multiple parents, I can think of a should query:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "should": [
            {
                parent_id: { 
                    type: my-child,
                    id: 1
                }
            },
            {
                parent_id: { 
                    type: my-child,
                    id: 2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Where `my-child` is the value of the join field `my-join-field` defined in you mapping for both of the queries above. Check the full [Parent-Child setup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-parent-id-query.html) for additional info from this. If you don't have the join field defined in your mappings, it will throw an error.

If you want to get all the children from all the parents, you can simply:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match":{
            "my-join-field": "my-child"
        }
    }
}
```

This will bring back all the children without the parents.

You can use the [Has parent query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html) as well but keep in mind that the performance of this particular query is slow.

If you want to get all the docs, parents and children:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all":{}
    }
}
```

But if you have additional documents that are no part of the parents or children relationships:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "must":{
            "exists":{
                "field": "my-join-field"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will exclude all the docs WITHOUT the field `my-join-field`

Remember that ElasticSearch is not intended to be like a relational ER-database like SQL. The Parent-Child is just intended to be a 1-n relation. Relations n-n are not supported.

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: Thank! I knew this, but I thought maybe there is some other way)))